# Memory increase in javafx with 3d

Tags: javafx

I’m learning javafx to create a scene with 3D objects and I met a problem.
I created a semplificated class to describe the problem.

The Group “allPyr” has a lot of Mesh managed by the variable “numberPyr” ( with 2 “for” cicles). The Timeline variates “numberPyr” continuously from 1 to 100.
Which is the correct way to update the Group “allPyr”?
I tried this way ( and I’m sure is wrong) because the ram of my pc increase proportionally by increasing the number of mesh ( and I can understand it) but then doesn’t decrease when the mesh are few ( the program after some cycles goes out of memory).
As ‘’ dirty’’ solution I call the garbage collector and let clean it in order to free the ram. It does work but I’m sure this is not the correct or best way to do it
Have you some suggestion?

```
public class MainFrameAnimatoTestRam extends Application{   
static int numberPyr=1;

public void start(Stage stage) {
    Group root = new Group(); 
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600, true);            
    stage.setScene(scene); 
    stage.show();
    
    Group allPyr = new Group();
    
    TriangleMesh geomPyr= createTriangleMesh();         
    root.getChildren().add(allPyr); 
      
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.1), event -> {
        if(numberPyr <100)                  
            numberPyr=numberPyr*2;
        else
            numberPyr=1;         
        updateAllPyr(geomPyr, allPyr, numberPyr);
    }));        
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();     
}    

static void updateAllPyr(TriangleMesh geometria, Group allPyr,int numberPyr) {
    allPyr.getChildren().clear();
    allPyr.getChildren().removeAll();       
    //System.gc();
    MeshView filtro=null;
    int larg,alt=0;
    for(int y=0;y<=numberPyr;y++) {
        larg=-3000;
        for(int x=0;x<=numberPyr;x++) {
            filtro=new MeshView(geometria);          
            filtro.setTranslateX(larg);
            filtro.setTranslateY(alt);
            allPyr.getChildren().add(filtro);
            filtro=null;
            larg=x*30;
        }
        alt=y*30;           
    }
}
        

static TriangleMesh createTriangleMesh(){         
    float h = 20;
    float s = 30;        
    TriangleMesh pyramid_mesh = new TriangleMesh();

    pyramid_mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(0, 0);
    pyramid_mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(2.0F, 0);
    pyramid_mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(1.0F, 0.0F);      
    pyramid_mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(2.0F, 2.0F);      
    pyramid_mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(0, 2.0F);
    pyramid_mesh.getPoints().addAll(
          0,  0,   0,               // Point 0 - Top
           0,  h, -s/2,             // Point 1 - Front
         -s/2, h,   0,              // Point 2 - Left
           0,  h,  s/2,             // Point 3 - Back
          s/2, h,   0 );            // Point 4 - Right         
    pyramid_mesh.getFaces().addAll(
     //  P,T   P,T   P,T
         0,2,  2,4,  1,3,           // Front left face
         0,2,  1,4,  4,3,           // Front right face
         0,2,  4,4,  3,3,           // Back right face
         0,2,  3,4,  2,3,           // Back left face
         3,1,  1,4,  2,0,           // Bottom rear face
         3,1,  4,3,  1,4   );       // Bottom front face         
    pyramid_mesh.getFaceSmoothingGroups().addAll(0,1,2,3,4,4);      
    return pyramid_mesh;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Application.launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "the program after some cycles goes out of memory"? Do you get an exception or what?

Comment: Yes i get an exception. i just updated javafx to the latest version and now the exception doesn't happen again